# Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/media/catalog/product/I/V/IVOC01_BLUE01_01_IMG1_12.jpg

Tags: product, magento2.1.0, edit

I want to edit my product attribute but while click on edit button for products,the above error am getting .

Answer (score 1):

Error is showing due to missing product image for product.

Add all product images to `media/catalog/product/`

Images should placing as per product image save path.

Upload product images, product edit action will work correctly.

Comment: You can accept my answer if really useful for you and very useful for other community use who can use it without any conflict.

Comment: Solve your issue or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Please run below sql code

```
SET @file = '/I/V/IVOC01_BLUE01_01_IMG1_12.jpg';
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE value = @file;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE value = @file;
COMMIT;
```